# React Navigation Error: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have followed the documentation and also the solutions from stackoverflow,I still keep getting the error.
This is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import MainScreen from './components/MainScreen';


export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AppStackNavigator />;
    }
}
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: MainScreen,
    },
});

export const Apps = createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator)


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost correct, just use Apps in you root component:

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: MainScreen,
    },
});

const Apps = createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator)

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Apps />;
    }
}
```