# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight')

Tags: react-native, expo

I tried changing the code in every way possible suggested on internet but still this error persists. I'm getting **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight')**

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';
import * as Expo from 'expo'
import  Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Dishdetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import { View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Menu: { screen: Menu },
    Dishdetail: { screen: Dishdetail}
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Menu',
    navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#512DAB'
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            color: '#fff'
        }
    }
});

class Main extends Component{

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1, paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight }}>
            <MenuNavigator />
            </View>
        );

    }
}

export default Main;
```

How should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, if you installed `expo-constants`, just use:

```
Constants.statusBarHeight
```

without `Expo.`.

So your code becomes:

```
class Main extends Component{

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1, paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : Constants.statusBarHeight }}>
            <MenuNavigator />
            </View>
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, if I remove Expo. then I'm getting error 'Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation v3 and v4 you must set up your app container' and if I keep Expo. and do import { Constants } from 'expo'; then the error remains same (evaluating 'Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight')

Comment: The query is solved. Thanks! After doing what you suggested I went to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093930/react-navigation-error-the-navigation-prop-is-missing-for-this-navigator.